# .Net Dns.GetHostAddresses(Domain) - return ipv6 address

Tags: .net

I've searched on this quite a bit and I'm still not having any luck. The issue is, if I nslookup from my server, if the host has an IPv6 address, I see it in the list. However, if I use .Net System.Net's Dns.GetHostAddresses(Domain), it only returns IPv4 addresses.

With a lot of reading, I found this: IPv6 addresses are filtered from the results of the GetHostAddresses method if the local computer does not have IPv6 installed.

I'm in an IPv4 only network. I don't need to ping or have actual network connectivity, I only need to return an IPv6 address for a host if it has one, which like I said, works with nslookup from the same server.

Could anyone tell me how to get an IPv6 address using .Net, even if you happen to be in an IPv4 only network?

Thanks

Comment: What is "Domain", the thing you're passing to GetHostAddresses?

Answer (score 0):

If I call GetHostAddresses("localhost") I get both IPV4 and IPV6 addresses.  So, in your network, whatever Domain contains, hasn't been assigned an IPv6 address.

Try:

```
var addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
```

What results do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can conver the IPV4 Address to IPV6 mapped address.

```
IPAddress ipv4Address = null;
IPAddress ipv6Address = null;
IPAddress[] ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);

foreach (IPAddress ip in ipAddresses)
{
     if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
     {
         ipv4Address = ip;
         ipv6Address = ip.MapToIPv6();
         Debug.Writeline("ipv4 address changed to ipv6 address " + ipv6Address.ToString());
     }
}
```